Why does KitchenAid dough hook move up the shaft?
I have a KitchenAid Professional 600 mixer. I use it almost exclusively for Kneading whole grain sourdough or other bread on speed 2. The sourdough is medium hydration. I purchased a spiral dough hook to fit the model. When I’m mixing the dough, I find that the dough hook moves up the shaft to the bottom of the notch, instead of remaining at the top of the notch, where it should be. This keeps the dough hook from reaching low enough in the bowl to mix thoroughly. I lubricate the mixer shaft often with vegetable oil.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Are you saying the hook itself moves, or that the dough works its way up to the top of the hook as it spins?

One way to avoid this would be adding a spring to the shaft that presses the hook downwards (old style Kitchen Aids had this fitted by the factory). See e.g. this video near the end: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqIhu4MAPGE.

very related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/81545/dough-getting-into-handheld-mixer, also see the answers to https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18941/in-my-new-mixer-my-bread-dough-gets-wrapped-around-the-kneading-hook-what-shou/18948#18948

This is just kind of what the spiral hook does. KitchenAid mixers used to have a sprung retaining plate which kept it from riding up as much, but even then it would wobble. The force of pushing the dough down pushes the hook up.
Neither the spiral nor the flat dough hook is particularly good at initial mixing. If you like, you can use the paddle until things get a little bit mixed and the motor starts to struggle, then switch to the hook.

I’m not affiliated in any way, but I got an aftermarket spring+washer from  https://www.mrmixer.store/parts/p/spring-washer-upgrade-for-kitchenaid-mixers for my mixer. $15 for such a simple part kinda sucks, but also it had bothered me enough that I got it anyway.

Much appreciated.
